# Replacing (background) node gives weird result / nodes not visible on screen

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm trying to get into game dev with SpriteKit for iOS, and I'm following a book called **iOS Games By Tutorials** by *Ray Wenderleich*.

Right now I'm working on a platform game, but I'm getting some weird results when trying to do something not in the book.

Basically I have a functioning platform game that loads the level from a JSON-file, and lays out bricks/ nodes in a background layer. I want to have  multiple **floors**, so when a user jumps through a portal in the game, a new floor/ level is loaded and placed on screen in the exact same position (all floors are the same size).

I didn't think I would have any troubles with this, as being notified when the user jumps through the portal is really easy. And I'm already loading a level to begin with, so loading another one at this time and replacing the original one shouldn't be hard.

However, it's proving to be very difficult. **When the game loads I call this method:**

```
- (void)createWorld {
  _bgLayer = [self createScenery:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]];

  _worldNode = [SKNode node];
  [_worldNode addChild:_bgLayer];
  [self addChild:_worldNode];

  self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
  _worldNode.position = CGPointMake(-_bgLayer.layerSize.width / 2, -_bgLayer.layerSize.height / 2);
}
```

This initializes a level (floor 1) from a JSON file, which basically is just a number of 32x32 nodes positioned next to each other forming a map. It then creates a `worldNode`, adds the `bgLayer` to the `worldNode`, and then adds it to the screen. Later it centers the `worldNode` on the screen. The `worldNode` is the node that moves when the player moves, the `bgLayer` is always stationary.

**When the user jumps through a portal, I call this method:**

```
- (void)goingUp {
  if (_isChangingFloor) return;  
  _isChangingFloor = YES;

  [_bgLayer removeFromParent];
  _bgLayer = nil;
  [_worldNode removeFromParent];
  _worldNode = nil;

  _bgLayer = [self createScenery:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]];
  _worldNode = [SKNode node];
  [_worldNode addChild:_bgLayer];
  [self addChild:_worldNode];

  _worldNode.position = CGPointMake(-_bgLayer.layerSize.width / 2, -_bgLayer.layerSize.height / 2);
}
```

This method wasn't always this "full", as I thought I could just replace `bgLayer` with the new one. That didn't work, so now I'm trying to reset everything, to replicate what happens in the `createWorld` method at start. However, this doesn't work either...

**This is the result I get after jumping through the portal:**
[image]

As you can see, there's 1 node on-screen, however the debug-info says there are 446. I believe this is the total number of nodes on the entire floor, but only around 90-100 should be visible at a time. I've tried adding/ removing nodes from the level, which increases/ decreases this number.

So as you all probably can understand, I'm really confused. Why doesn't it simply replace the old background with a new one when I jump through a portal? There's nothing wrong with the JSON-file itself, as I've tried loading `floor0` in at start, and that works fine. Why isn't the behavior the same when jumping through the portal as when I initially load the game? What is different here? Why does it say 446 nodes on-screen when there's clearly only 1. Why is there only 1 node on the screen?

I've been stuck on this for several days now, and I would really appreciate any help that would get me closer to a solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i think you should check the zposition of   _bgLayer  it wld be higher index every time you remove and add it may be this would reslove your problem

Comment: I tried logging the ``z-position`` for both the `_bgLayer` and `_worldNode`, but they're both the same before and after, so that doesn't seem to be the problem. But thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

i see that your scene has anchor point in the middle of screen 
should nod your world node position be CGPointZero to make the world be in center of scene?

```
_worldNode.position = CGPointZero;
```

instead of

```
 _worldNode.position = CGPointMake(-_bgLayer.layerSize.width / 2, -_bgLayer.layerSize.height / 2);
```